# Does adding an adapter to "convert" ports slow down the transfer rate?

Tags: motherboard, port, pci, esata

I want to add an eSATA port and am looking at [Internal SATA to eSATA II External](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812119021) and [PCI controller to eSATA](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816132007). Are these solutions slower than if the motherboard has eSATA (or any other port for that matter) built-in?

Answer (score 1):

An adapter will slow down the connection insignificantly and isn't worth the trouble of buying a new motherboard.